# jquery-countdown plugin, changing height and width

Tags: jquery, countdowntimer

I am using [this plugin](http://reflejo.github.com/jquery-countdown/) for a countdown clock

Its great, but I need it to be smaller, and when I adjust the height and the width of the code and PNG, everything gets thrown off.  I change the height and width to the same ratio it was originally created in:

```
digitWidth: 67,
digitHeight: 90,
```

changed to:

```
digitWidth: 30,
digitHeight: 41,
```

And made change the PNG to a width of 30px as well.  Is there anything else I can do so the numbers do not get all screwed up when I change the size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep your

```
digitWidth:30px,
digitHeight:40.15px
```

and after you initialize the conter by the function

```
.countdown({});
```

add this line

```
$('.cntDigit').each(function(i,v){$(v).css('background-size','30px')})
```

there is a problem with the `background-size`

Comment: The numbers still seem to be off, you can see a demo here: http://demo.omnigon.com/christian_bovine/bellatorbuild/countdown.html

Comment: I found the sweet spot, the DigitHeight needs to be: 40.32px